# Miniconda and Command prompt not running

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, anaconda, command-line-interface, miniconda

I tried unistalling miniconda from windows through add or remove programs, and while uninstalling i got this pop up[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFLbQ.png) and uninstalled miniconda.

But after that, I couldn't access command prompt on Windows.
And in VS Code terminal getting the error :

> The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.

Methods i have tried so far:
**Scan C drive for error** ,
*system restore to last state*,
sfc scannow in powershell

I reinstalled miniconda but can't open miniconda prompt too, and conda is not running from powershell too. I already add conda to path variable.
I am not getting any error in powershell while running `conda info -e , conda , conda activate` but it's not working either.

Answer (score 3):

Try running this command on your PowerShell CLI:

```
C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe DELETE "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
```

Comment: That worked for me! After I installed miniconda, Command Prompt exited once I opened it. This helped to bring it back.